# Firebase crashlytics upgradation issue in Android and unable to connect to backend

Tags: firebase, okhttp, crashlytics-android

I am getting below error “**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'okhttp3.HttpUrl okhttp3.Request.url()' on a null object reference”** (Build is successful getting error on launch of application ) after upgrading the Fabric to firebase crashlytics by following the steps from below link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

without upgradation changes the app is working fine
Please help me resolve the issue

I am using

- Android Studio 4.1
- Java 8
- Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.0
- Gradle Version 6.5

**App/build.gradle**

```java
dependencies {
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["firebase-core"]
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["firebase-messaging"]
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["firebase-performance"]
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

**Project/build.gradle**

```java
minSdkVersion    : 21,
targetSdkVersion : 30,

def dependVersion = [
    support    : "28.0.0",
    retrofit   : "2.9.0",
    okhttp     : "4.9.0",
    dagger2    : "2.0.2",
    butterknife: "8.2.1",
    glide      : "4.1.1",
    firebase   : "11.6.0",
    firebase_performance : "19.0.7",
    qualtrics   : "0.1.1",
    firebase_crashlytics : "2.9.3",
    secure_preferences : "0.1.7"
]


dependencies = [
"firebase-core"             : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core",
"firebase-messaging"        : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging",
"firebase-performance"      : "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf",
]

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
}
```

Comment: can you add some logs?

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'okhttp3.HttpUrl okhttp3.Request.url()' on a null object reference